# Reformating dataframe R

Tags: r, dataframe, reformatting

trying to reformat my dataframe to show all the stock names as column headers in one place. So first column would be date columns 2 onwards would be the stocks.

```
Prices<-bdh(stocks, "PX_LAST", start.date = (as.Date("2019-06-14")), end.date = (as.Date("2019-06-21")), options = optW)
Prices<-data.frame(Prices)
```

Output :

```
      $`JKH SL Equity`
    date PX_LAST
    1 2019-06-14   138.3
    2 2019-06-21   138.7

    $`700 HK Equity`
    date PX_LAST
    1 2019-06-14   330.0
    2 2019-06-21   354.4

    $`BHP LN Equity`
    date PX_LAST
    1 2019-06-14    1910
    2 2019-06-21    1965

    $`ALL AU Equity`
    date PX_LAST
    1 2019-06-14   30.62
    2 2019-06-21   31.06
```

Would like to have 3 rows, one for column name, and the other two for the two prices.

Answer (score 0):

An option would be `Map` to loop through the `list` and `cbind` to create the 'new' column from the `names` of the `list`

```
Map(cbind, lst1, new = names(lst1))
```

Comment: what is there are differing number of rows?

Comment: @user11690874  The `Map` returns a `list` of data.frame, so it wouldn't matter as it is creating a column in each of the list elements

Comment: sorry let me rephrase, would like the list above to be shown as 5 columns. First col would be the date, column 2 -5 would be the JKH Equity etc etc.with the prices values as rows (first col rows would be the dates)